# Gatsby Contentful CMS error when deploying to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, gatsby, contentful

Trying to deploy an application to Heroku and in the client-side building step it can't find the Contentful API keys.

The variables are in a ".env.production" and ".env.development" files. 
When running locally both production and development files are read and the variables are found. 
Although, when deploying to Heroku when building the client side, I get the following error:

```
remote: error Problems with gatsby-source-contentful plugin options:
remote: spaceId: undefined - "spaceId" is required
remote: accessToken: undefined - "accessToken" is required
remote: host (default value): "cdn.contentful.com"
remote: environment (default value): "master"
remote: downloadLocal (default value): false
remote: localeFilter (default value): [Function]
remote: forceFullSync (default value): false
remote: pageLimit (default value): 100
remote: useNameForId (default value): true
remote:        not finished onPreBootstrap - 0.019s
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 build: `gatsby build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.J7KKr/_logs/2020-06-04T02_01_57_062Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 build: `cd client && npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.J7KKr/_logs/2020-06-04T02_01_57_090Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run install-client && npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.J7KKr/_logs/2020-06-04T02_01_57_122Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
```

The error of not finding the spaceId and accessToken only happens when deploying.

gatsby-config.js

```
let env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"

console.log(`using enviroment config: ${env}`)
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.env.*` are likely not checked into git (they shouldn't be.) If so, you have to set environment variables on Heroku separately, either via the heroku cli, or heroku dashboard.

```sh
heroku config:set CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID=myspaceid
```

See the [docs for more information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Answer (score 0):

According to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11559) (and it's like Gatsby environment variables work in some platforms), you need to prefix all your `.env` variables with `GATSBY_` prefix. So, your:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  },
},
```

Will become:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  },
},
```

Of course, you need also to change the name in your `.env` files.

Another required thing is the `.dotenv` the snippet that you already have, so just prefixing your variables with `GATSBY_` you should be able to deploy it without issues.